# How to import packages from a project to another

Tags: java, spring, package

I have two projects (let say project A and project B) the two works with Spring( The same version)the only difference is that the first one has an Eclipse IDE and the second one STS  and I want to use and work with the project A  in the project B.

I've tried to manually copy/past a number of classes but the classes are so much dependent between them it makes it impossible.

I expect to show me how to import/export project A and use it in project B

Comment: are you using maven? if the project A has a pom file then you can import it directly from project B, in their pom

Comment: if you use maven or gradle you can build a jar file of project A and add dependency of it to project B

Comment: I am using maven yes can you please provide an example or something that's show me the way

Comment: if you use maven, you then have a gropuId and artifactId for each project so you can just add
 <dependency>
            <groupId>your group id</groupId>
            <artifactId>your artifact id</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Basically project A should be in your build path. Any of the two ways works

- Export your project A as jar and add the jar to your Project B's build path.
- Projects BuildPath > Projects > Add your project A.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer i will try it and give you a feedback

Answer (score 0):

Basically the one above me is really close , but If you will export project A to jar it might be not work if you want use it on server (Tomcat for example).
So you can make it "Runnable jar" from the first place and then as he said :
project B (right click) >>>> build path >>>> configuration path >>> libraries >>> add external jar >> and browser when you saved the jar. 
now you can make instance of projects A classes and the functions already inheritance .
glad it helps you :)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer i will try it and give you a feedback